# r create a column for grep function word

Tags: r

I want to grep a word from a sentence and create a new column for the word.

This is what I have done so far.

```
Keyword <- "statistics|regression|logistic"

data_keyword <- data[grep(keyword, data$description, ignore.case = T),]
```

So the data looks like

```
id  description 
1   ~~~~~~statistics ~~~
2   ~~~~~~regression ~~~
```

And I want to create a new column that shows which word leads to grep the id 1 and 2.

So what I desire looks like below

```
id  description  words
1   ~~~~~~statistics ~~~ statistics
2   ~~~~~~regression ~~~ regression
```

I think I can use mutate but not sure how to code it. Any idea would be helpful.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you provide some sample data you are working with and use the `dput` function on it, and then paste the results in your question? In this way people are facilitated in helping you. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use `sub`:

```
keys <- sprintf(".*(%s).*", keyword)

data$words <- sub(keys, "\\1", data$description)
data

#   id          description      words
# 1  1 ~~~~~~statistics ~~~ statistics
# 2  2 ~~~~~~regression ~~~ regression
```